# d3 graph freezes with highcharts

Tags: d3.js, highcharts

i am currently working with the d3 library. I have an HTML file which will load 2 external js scripts. One script will create a d3 forced graph and the other one will create a highcharts graph.

The issue that im currently facing is that the graph layout is freezing when the highchart chart is plotted. I used a timeout to delay the plotting of the chart so i can be certain that the chart is the problem. When the chart is plotted the following error is thrown:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'x' of undefined
```

with the following code:

```
force.on("tick", function ()
{
link.attr("x1", function (d) {return d.source.x;})
    .attr("y1", function (d) {return d.source.y;})
    .attr("x2", function (d) {return d.target.x;})
    .attr("y2", function (d) {return d.target.y;});

d3.selectAll("circle")
    .attr("cx", function (d) {return d.x;})  //<- error
    .attr("cy", function (d) {return d.y;});

d3.selectAll("text")
    .attr("x", function (d) {return d.x;})   //<- error
    .attr("y", function (d) {return d.y;});
});
```

I have no idea why highcharts should have side effects on the d3 library.

Thanks for any suggestions

[EDIT] Minimal example

html file loading the scripts:

```
<head>
    <!-- d3 library -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/d3.min.js"></script>
    <!-- highchart library -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/highcharts.min.js"></script>
    <!-- chart style -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/chart_style.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- here the d3 graph gets created -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/d3_script.js"></script>

    <!-- here the chart gets created -->
    <!--<script type="text/javascript" src="js/chart.js"></script>-->
</body>
```

d3 script:

```
// Setup
var color = d3.scale.category20();
var width = window.innerWidth;
var height = window.innerHeight;
var power = -100;
var distance = 100;
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg").attr("width", '100%').attr("height", height);
var force = d3.layout.force().charge(power).linkDistance(distance).size([width, height]);
var graph = {nodes:[{name : "A"}, {name : "B"}], links: [{source: 0, target : 1}]};
force.nodes(graph.nodes).links(graph.links).start();

// Tooltip
var tooltip = d3.select("body").append("div")
    .attr("class", "tooltip")
    .style("opacity", 0);

// Links
var link = svg.selectAll(".link")
    .data(graph.links)
    .enter().append("line")
    .attr("class", "link")
    .style("stroke-width", function (d) { return 1});

// Nodes
var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
    .data(graph.nodes)
    .enter()
    .append("g")
    .attr("class", "node")
    .attr("id", function(d){ return "group-" + d.group})
    .call(force.drag)
    .append("circle")
    .attr("r", 8)
    .style("fill", function (d) {return color(d.group); })
    .on("mouseover", function(d,i) {
        tooltip.transition().duration(200).style("opacity", .9);
        tooltip.html(d.name)
        .style("left", (d3.event.pageX - d.name.length*3) + "px")
        .style("top", (d3.event.pageY - 35) + "px");
    })
    .on("mouseout", function(d) {
        tooltip.transition().duration(500).style("opacity", 0);
    });

// Update
force.on("tick", function ()
{
    link.attr("x1", function (d) {return d.source.x;})
        .attr("y1", function (d) {return d.source.y;})
        .attr("x2", function (d) {return d.target.x;})
        .attr("y2", function (d) {return d.target.y;});

    d3.selectAll("circle")
        .attr("cx", function (d) {return d.x;})
        .attr("cy", function (d) {return d.y;});

    d3.selectAll("text")
        .attr("x", function (d) {return d.x;})
        .attr("y", function (d) {return d.y;});
});
```

chart script:

```
setTimeout(function()
{
    document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].innerHTML += "<div id='dummy'></div>";Highcharts.chart('dummy', {series: [{name: 'Test1', data: [0, 1, 2, 3]}]});
}, 2000);
```

Comment: Hi @chriszo, could you provide me some minimal live working example, which shows your issue?

Comment: provided a minimal example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem through a timeout function for the graph. Somehow it is oke when the graph is plotted first.